# SQL: date type column with only mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a column of data type having only 'mm-dd' values.
Is it possible and if yes how should I do it?

Note: Instead of "*2022-06-07*", I want "*07-06*"

Comment: It really depends on the DBMS you're using. What's your DBMS? @JunGi

Comment: @lemon Hello. I'm using Transact (MS SQL Server).

Comment: Can this just be a string in that format, or does it have to have actual datetime - type functionality?

Comment: @PhilipKelley Hi. Yes, it's listed as datetime type, which is why I'm struggling atm :(

Comment: Then the requirement doesn't make sense. It's like saying I want you to go to the BMW dealership and get me an X5 with square wheels. At some point you're going to have to break it to me that my requirement also makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `date` type that can store that format - in fact none of the date types store a date and/or time in any of the formats you typically recognize.

For your specific requirement, that looks like a `char(5)` for the data type, but how you constrain it so that it will only accept valid date values, I have no idea. You'd think this would work:

```
CHECK (TRY_CONVERT(date, string_column + '-2022', 105) IS NOT NULL)
```

But what about leap years? February 29th is sometimes valid, but you've thrown away the only information that can make you sure. What a bunch of mess to store your favorite string and trust that people aren't putting garbage in there.

Honestly I would store the date as a `date`, then you can just have a computed column (or a column in a view, or just do this at query time:

```
d_slash_m_column AS CONVERT(char(5), date_column, 105)
```

Why not just in your query (or only in a view) say:

```
[output] = CONVERT(char(5), data_in_the_right_type, 105)
```

?

I'd personally stay away from `FORMAT()`, for reasons I've described here:

- [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)
- [FORMAT is a convenient but expensive function - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7144/sql-date-format-comparison-sql-format-sql-convert/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [FORMAT is a convenient but expensive function - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7145/sql-date-format-comparison-computed-column-materialized-column/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the great reply. The reason why I'm asking is that I have to create a table with certain values (datetime column having '14 feb', '12 jan' values).

Comment: That's for the presentation layer to show, not the data engine to store, @JunGi . A .Net language can easily display the date `2022-06-06` as `Jun 06` with the format style `MMM-dd`. Sounds like you might have an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: Appreciate your research on the `FORMAT` function a lot, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL Server [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function:

```
FORMAT(col1, 'dd/MM')
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2b8c0a704839021624105a06106a480).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. But is there a way to make the same operation in CREATE TABLE?

Comment: There's no SQL Server `DATE` type that allows you to declare only part of a date as type, unless you use the `VARCHAR` type inside a `CREATE TABLE` statement. Can you make an example of what you need? @JunGi

Comment: I had a picture of a table that I must create in SQL. It had 'Date_last' column with datetime type having values only like '14 feb', '12 Jan' etc. I thought I could create a common datetime column and then extract month and day, but maybe I'm missing something and there is a way to make it happen during creating table.

Comment: @JunGi Then ask the person that gave you that picture / assignment many questions. The datetime datatype stores information in an unreadable, binary format. Do **not** confuse graphical representation with content.

Comment: @JunGi Are you sure what they showed in the picture is actually what they want and not just dummy information thrown onto the picture? `'14 feb'` doesn't make a whole lot of sense _without the year_ and sounds like something Excel might have done to the information (also that's not the format you describe in the question, which would be `'14-02'`).

Answer (score 0):

In such cases using char or varchar is not the best option as in those cases the underlying DB constraints that validate the integrity of the data do not kick in.

Best option is to use an arbitrary year and then put in a proper date, so for example for storing 01-Jan, the db column should store proper date with year as any arbitrary value, e.g. 2000.  So your db should say 2000-01-01.

With such a solution you are still able to rely on the DB to raise an error if you tried month 13.  Similarly sorting will work naturally as well.

Comment: They know the year, they just want the appearance of it being day-month. It doesn’t mean you should throw away the year and use an arbitrary one in its place - you lose the ability to determine whether 29-02 is valid or not, for example.